# Lost user files when upgrading windows. How can I recover files? (windows.old folder did not capture other user accounts)

Tags: windows, data-recovery, windows.old

Due to an issue with booting, I had to reinstall windows 7 over an existing windows 10 installation. I chose the option which allows you to keep your old windows files through the windows.old folder that gets created when you reinstall windows...

Prior to this reinstallion today, my previous version of windows already had windows.old, windows.old1 and a windows.old2.

I assumed this process would have continued, but when I checked the windows.old folder it only had saved user account folders for my two guest accounts "Guest" and "family". This is rather peculiar as there were 3 other admin accounts that I had used frequently but those don't seem to have been moved/saved?!

Any Ideas as to what I can do to recover my files?

I'm useing EaseUS data recovery on a separate partition and am running a deep scan as we speak.

Should I create an image of my c: drive in case something else manages to break and I lose my chances of recovering any of my files? (if so what application should I use?)

Any advice on how I can recover my files would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Data recovery tools are your only possible solution.

Answer (score 0):

If you've reinstalled Windows, there's very little chance of recovering any files at all, because they will almost certainly have been overwritten, so it's probably a hopeless case, I'm afraid.

You can try running Recuva (http://www.piriform.com/recuva/download) or something similar on your C drive, but you really shouldn't hold out too much hope.

I've been telling people for years not to use the "my documents"/"my [whatever]" directories because of precisely this.

If you keep your personal files *anywhere else* on the device, then you can do a refresh-reinstall of Windows without losing anything, because the only non-OS directories wiped by the refresh are the "My..." directories; all other directories are left untouched.

Is this an incredibly stupid design flaw?  I'll let you decide, because you're the one suffering for it.

If you really, really like using the "My..." directories, take copies of them before refreshing the OS (just right-click drag the logged-in user's dir to any non-system dir, and select "Copy here") -- but it's still safer to not use them, in case the machine just dies without giving you the chance to copy them.

Sorry for your loss, but at least you'll know for next time.